# Specially or especially

Tags: sentence

I need to send out an invite for a group to attend a training programme which will be held soon. I intend to know which is the right choice of word "specially" or "especially".

Is this sentence correct for the above request.

"Please ensure you attend this session as it is organized specially for you".

Answer (score 0):

According to Etymology Online Dictionary: specially (adv.)

late 13c., from special(adj.) + -ly (2). A doublet of especially.
I can add that 
'specially' is an abbreviation of 'especially', like 'phone - telephone'.
There is a tendency: the abbreviated form is more informal than non-abbreviated one.